# I have created tables using @Entity but what if there are always addition and deletion of columns in table in springboot jpa application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

have created spring boot rest api, with spring boot JPA , I have created tables using @Entity but what if there is always change in columns. There are always addition and deletion of columns in tables on daily basis. How can I handle this type of scenario.

I didn't use the entity classes. What I did was just hit the query and get resultset in map. Then I use the map in json response

Comment: I doubt you are modifying the columns. You are probably meant to say records? Also you shouldn't let JPA manage your tables use something like flyway for that.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest working with JDBC and native queries instead of JPA, also you can later create an entity or a DTO to assign attributes (you wont be needing annotations).

exemple :

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public List<Map<String, Object>> getAllEmployees() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
} }
```

The endpoint :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@GetMapping
public List<Map<String, Object>> getAllEmployees() {
    return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
}
```

}

you might also implement your queries in a separate class called DAO and then do the rest of the implementation in the service class